# Defining a fallback service for Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube

Is it possible to have a fallback service for Kubernetes ingresses in the event that none of the normal pods are live/ready? In other words, how would you go about presenting a friendly "website down" page to visitors if all pods crashed or went down somehow?

Right now, a page appears that says "default backend - 404" if that happens.

Here's what we tried, to no avail:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: website-down-service
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: example-service
              servicePort: 80
```

For reference, we're testing locally with Minikube and deploying to the cloud on Google's Container Engine.

Comment: Could you attach `kubectl describe ing example-ingress` please?

Answer (score 3):

If using Nginx then [default backend](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#default-backend) annotation should do the trick, sample:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-name
  namespace: your-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: fallback-backend
spec:
   <your spec here>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the Nginx Ingress Controller there is a flag `--default-backend-service`, which currently points to the service showing the "default backend - 404" message. Just replace it with the service you want. See https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx#command-line-arguments

If you're using another Ingress Controller, I expect it to have a similar option.

Comment: The link provided is broken .  Do you have a working link?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/0.9.6/controllers/nginx#command-line-arguments
Note: it is OLD